# ASP.Net WebApp Performance Issue

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, performance, application-pool

I've been working in a ASP.Net WebApp which takes long time to load a particular ASPX Page. After first time the page is loaded in browser, next time onward this issue is not replaceable in Production.

**Update**

I added some log and looks like below query is taking 1 minute 20 sec to execute. Can you please help me to optimize it ? What's actually wrong in the query that it takes so long first time ?

Log :

"11/12/15","22:24:24","ExecuteSql - ---4---- ","9",""

"11/12/15","22:25:44","ExecuteSql - ---5---- ","9",""

Query:

SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(varchar(15), Period_End_Date, 107) as PDate FROM PBHISTORY..STATEMENT_OF_CHANGE ORDER BY Period_End_Date DESC","7",""

C# Code:

public string GetDateRangeReportingDate(int reportId)
        {
            LogActivityVerbose("GetDateRangeReportingDate - before GetReportInfoById ");
            var report = GetReportInfoById(reportId);
            LogActivityVerbose("GetDateRangeReportingDate - after GetReportInfoById ");

```
        string sql = string.Format(@"SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(varchar(15), Period_End_Date, 107) as PDate FROM {0}..{1}
                                           ORDER BY Period_End_Date DESC", _historyDatabase, report.SourceTableName);

        LogActivityVerbose("GetDateRangeReportingDate - before ExecuteSql ");
        var data = ExecuteSql(sql);
        LogActivityVerbose("GetDateRangeReportingDate - after ExecuteSql ");
        while (data.Read())
        {
            return data["PDate"].ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution of my performance issue I mentioned above. Issue was wrong indexing in table and I fixed this issue by changing the indexing of table where from we are fetching records in production.

Also, I fixed Framework level entity class by using SQL Data Adapter and using statements. App runs super fast in production. Thanks for your help.

private string ExecuteSqlNew(string sql)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PBReportCS"].ConnectionString;
            string commandTimeOut = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PBReportCommandTimeout"].ToString();
            DataSet result = new DataSet();
            string pDate = "";

```
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = int.Parse(commandTimeOut);
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    adapter.Fill(result);
                    adapter.Dispose();
                    conn.Close();
                    pDate = result.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PDate"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return pDate;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

- Are you deploying a debug build vs release build (debug build will not contain compiler optimizations and will load up the debug symbols)?
- Are your app pools recycling too often?
- Are you loading lots of data on page start up in some sort of initialization?
- Also keep in mind on the initial load of a new ASP .net precompiled assembly will be Jitted on start so that does take some time as well.

**More possibilities:**

[Web site takes unusually long time to start the first time it is accessed, (Up to 68 seconds in total)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228632/web-site-takes-unusually-long-time-to-start-the-first-time-it-is-accessed-up-t)

*and*

[Fixing slow initial load for IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386471/fixing-slow-initial-load-for-iis)

I would check these things first.

Comment: Thanks very much. I put some log and looks like this issue has something to do with query based on Log. Below Method takes more than a minute to perform. Can you suggest something to optimize it ?